# Remove white border around a surface view

Tags: android, border, surfaceview

i have a surface view inside a  relativelayout. I want the surfaceview to cover the whole screen but it has a white border around it. How can i remove that border.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.paint.drawx.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

  <com.paint.drawx.ImageSurface
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your padding in your RelativeLayout. The padding settings tell your layout that it wants its contents pushed in from the layout "edges" by the set amount. Get rid of that and it will tell your layout that it wants its contents flush with its edges.

Comment: @user3190959 Feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you :)